# "Boolean ftp_home_dir not defined" CentOS 7 error

Tags: ftp, centos, vsftpd

I was installing vsftpd on CentOS 7 and when I run

## setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on

Server results: Boolean ftp_home_dir is not defined

I needed run it for SELinux allows users to work on FTP.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try running this:

```
setsebool -P tftp_home_dir on
```

Comment: on CentOS 7.3+ its  setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access 1 instead